# Не двигается ползунок у input range

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hook

Всем привет!

Не работает ползунок у input range хотя его value меняется.

У меня два input  в один вводится число и input range подстраивается под него. Либо когда меняем значение input range оно же и меняется в обычном input.

Все хорошо работает только если менять input range , а если поменять значение обычного input то ползунок стоит на том же месте.

[image: красный обычный инпут , желтый range input]

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState(20);
   const [range, setRange] = useState((20 / 500) * 100);
   const handleChange = (valueInp) => {
      const value = (valueInp / 500) * 100;
      setRange(value);
   };
   useEffect(() => {
      handleChange(value)
   }, [value]);
   return (
      <div className={mainContainer}>
         <p className={mainTitle}>
            Сколько квадратных метров помещение, которое нуждается в уборке?
         </p>
         <input
            className={outputInput}
            value={value}
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
               setValue(+e.target.value);
            }}
         />
         <div className={middle}>
            <div className={sliderContainer}>
               <span className={bar}>
                  <span style={{ width: `${range}%` }} className={fill}></span>
               </span>
               <input
                  className={slider}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                     setValue(e.target.value);
                     handleChange(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  type="range"
                  min="0"
                  max="500"
                  defaultValue={value}
               />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Стили :

```css
.outputInput {
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #94efff;
   margin-top: 30px;
}
.sliderContainer {
   position: relative;
   top: 50px;
}
.sliderContainer .bar {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 2px;
   top: 7px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #c7f7ff;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.sliderContainer .bar .fill {
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #0ac2b7;
}
.sliderContainer .slider {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   outline: none;
   background-color: transparent;
}
.sliderContainer .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   background-color: #0ac2b7;
   border-radius: 50%;
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: none;
   margin-top: 0.6rem;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(98, 0, 238, 0.1);
   transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.sliderContainer .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(235, 231, 240, 0.1);
}
.sliderContainer .slider:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.062);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо передать значение состояния компонента в `input type='range'`

```
<input
    className={slider}
    value={value} // <-- Вот так
    onChange={(e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
        handleChange(e.target.value);
    }}
    type="range"
    min="0"
    max="500"
    defaultValue={value}
/>
```

Ползунок будет сам считать %. Надо ограничить поле с вводом данных до вашего max=500